# ClassNotFoundException selenium when deploying EJB project

Tags: java, selenium, jboss, wildfly

I wanted to deploy my EJB project on a WildFly server, but when I publish it, WildFly cannot recognize selenium web driver and I get this error:

```
17:29:29,502 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ejb.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ejb.jar".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "ejb.jar"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:163)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class FNFIS.AutomationTest.test.LogInSteps with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:57)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:107)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:92)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:156)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebDriver;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver from [Module "deployment.ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
... 15 more
```

Comment: How is the driver installed?

Comment: i added selenium library in build path and the project works fine but when i deploy it, i get this error

Comment: You'll need to install it as a module or deploy the driver. Have a look at the class loading documentation http://docs.wildfly.org/13/Developer_Guide.html#Class_Loading_in_WildFly.